# Pass a parameter to a function from a DLL in c++

Tags: c++, opengl, dll, sdl

I have managed to call a function from a DLL in C++, but I would like to pass a parameter to it.

I am currently using SDL and I would like to pass the SDL event 'event' to the function in my source. Example below:

```
// DLL
typedef void (*Events)(SDL_Event *event);
static __declspec(dllexport) void HandleEvents(Events events)
{
    events(&d2Main::event);
}

// Application
int main()
{
    d2Main::HandleEvents(&HandleEvents);
}

void HandleEvents(SDL_Event *events)
{
     if(events.type == SDL_QUIT)
          // Do stuff
}
```

The d2Main is a class.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use nm utility (GNU binary utilities) to look at the symbol tables in the dll file and then call it the same way you call a regular function by wrapping the function you want to call using the extern "C" { your function} declaration. Your function should be linked by the linker therefore you should also add  -L ./ -ldllfile as a switch to g++ or gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose d2Main::event is static SDL_Event object. Yes it is possible. As long as the definition of the structure SDL_Event as seen by the application and the DLL is the same (including padding and packing that goes between elements inside the structure - for member aligment reasons).

Some things to remember when working across module boundaries are,

1. Ensure structures are compiled using the same definition
2. Better to use the same version of the same compiler. Because e.g. VS 8 and VS 9 ships with their own C/C++ runtimes and there by using their own individual heaps. So, a memory allocated from one module using VS 8 cannot be deleted from a module compiled using VS 9. Often this problem manifests as failures like "my dll crashes when I assign memory to std::string passed in as reference to my dll's export function"
3. Ensure to not mix modules built for Release and Debug configurations (same reasons - the heaps are different in release and debug CRT).